# How to implement PayPal Advanced Silent Post properly?

Tags: asp.net, iframe, paypal, paypal-ipn

I have implemented PayPal's Payments Advanced with Template C to handle both PayPal payments and Credit Cards without 'leaving' my website. I've coded my own cart successfully in Net (VB). I have token request web.request and the IFRAME built on the token response working. My mega-confusion is this: In the setup in PayPal Manager, you indicate a 'return' page, but ALSO indicate a 'Silent Post' page that receives the transaction results from a successful Credit Card or PayPal payment transaction, and a Silent Post FAIL page if the transaction fails.

What I don't understand, and what no one at PayPal seems to be able to clarify is how to handle the Silent Post page. I understand how to process the transaction validation from PayPal after payment is made, and how to break out of the IFrame, but don't understand a simple concept:

Shouldn't the RETURN page and the SILENT POST page be one and the same? If not, how would one handle the POST data?

I want to process the VALIDATED order AFTER I get verification from PayPal, not before (although I am also posting it in a 'pre-approval' database table as PENDING so if it blows up, I at least have the customer's order items and can help them complete the order...) So, what I've been doing is using the same page for SILENT POST as RETURN, pulling out the transaction success and posting the order on the same page, then telling the customer 'SUCCESSFUL ORDER' and showing them a button where they can see/print their full invoice.

Very confusing for a mid-level programmer. IS this an improper approach?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You may use any URL you wish to receive the silent post information. The best guide with more information on the silent post is the following: https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/developer/docs/pdf/pp_payflowlink_guide.pdf

Comment: Appreciate your help!! - I've been using that doc for months now, think I can quote it in my sleep. I've been up and running for months (just fine) WITHOUT the Silent Post. The doc glosses over Silent Post, and no, I don't get a response to both pages - used Fiddler and other tools - result: not even looking for my SP page set up in PayPal Manager. C# and PHP examples by PayPal don't use Silent Post.- PayPal tech has been great on phone but they have no idea how to do it, either. Code examples by PP were deprecated. Just wanted that extra layer of security. You were very nice to respond!

Answer (score 0):

I found what I believe to be the best answer: This 'Silent Post' boils down to being a simple `web.request` like the [example in C# here](http://stephenvillesbrownguy.com/main/asp-net-and-silent-post/).

One thing I suspect might be incorrect in PayPal's documentation (not sure of this!) is that silent post doesn't get a response from PayFlow. Rather, PayPal's IP addresses show that their Silent Post data comes from another source (see this list of IP addresses for PayPal; note the one under 'Silent Post'). This is still confusing, because I don't believe this server integrates with PayPal Advanced, but I've abandoned this idea of 'two responses' from PayPal and am using the `web.request` and `Request.Form` in my code-behind.